# Issues with creating working Docker image for non-root user

Tags: linux, docker

I want to create a docker image using a base image (non root) which will run serve static http assets.
So base Debian image has NodeJS already and I want to use NPM package http-server to serve the assets.
My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM mwi_node10_20190321
USER root
RUN useradd -u 5000 node
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/app

WORKDIR /home/node/app
RUN npm install --global http-server

USER node
COPY --chown=node:node . .
```

When I then try and run http-server using:

```
docker container run -it --user node 46c476f9dac5 http-server
```

I get the following error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
> container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec:
> "http-server": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.

However, if I run under root user then it works without any issues using cmd:

```
docker container run -it --user node 46c476f9dac5 http-server
```

So looks like a permission issue with running it as non-rooted but not sure how to resolve it. Any ideas?

Comment: You could `docker run --rm -it 46c476f9dac5 /bin/bash` to get an interactive shell in the image to poke around and see what the relevant permissions are.  The command at the end will override the `CMD` in the Dockerfile.

Comment: @DavidMaze I have been doing that but my linux skills are basic so not sure what I need to do be able to give access to the node user.

Comment: People who downvote, would be good if they explain why but I guess that's the nature of stackoveflow currently. Be constructive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok managed to resolve it by adding the permissions for the node user, not sure if it's the best approach so happy to take feedback on it, here's what I did to resolve it using my updated Dockerfile:

```
FROM mwi_node10_20190321
USER root
RUN useradd -u 5000 node
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/app
RUN chmod 755 /opt/mdw/node-v10.15.3-linux-x64/

WORKDIR /home/node/app
RUN npm install --global http-server

USER node
COPY ./dist/apps/designer/ /webapplication/
WORKDIR /webapplication/
CMD ["http-server", "-s"]
```